# iPad keyboard changes viewport on orientation change

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a very unique bug with iPad3 iOS6. I have a website that needs to be stared as a web app from the home screen.

I have a very simple viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` and I am using https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix for advanced viewport bug elimination.

However, when the keyboard is opened and you type in an input and decide to switch landscape per se, the viewport does not scale right. And vice versa. This does not happen when the website is in the Safari browser, only when it is webApp on the homescreen.

I have tested every possible viewport combination and have deleted all types of js, css. Even with plain html the bug keeps on happening.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!